# Do attack spells without attack rolls automatically hit?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

So, In the past I have always treated spells like magic missile as autohits. It's how I understand the rules, but i have a new house rule enacting a concentration check (DC SL+5) for *any* spell cast in combat since my magic users want to roll anyway. My question is **have I been adjudicating the "no roll" spells correctly?** Am I missing a step with magic missile (atm: player: *"I cast"* me:*"roll damage"*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Yes

Spells with Saving Throw: None and Spell Resistance: No, and which do not specify an attack roll or other contest to determine their effects, and which are cast by a character not subject to an arcane spell failure chance nor any other sort of spell failure chance come into effect without any any roll on the caster's part to determine their effects, usually.  You are not missing any steps in the casting of *magic missile* at least as regards its dealing damage.

Comment: He still must be aware of SR that magic missile is subject to, but as you said, no steps from the casting of magic missile are missing.